# Find original executable in subprocess

Tags: python-3.x

Assume my_application.exe starts multiple subprocesses. Are there any ways to find out the original path to my_application.exe from subprocess context? Traditional sys.argv[0] doesn't work in this case and just shows some value like '-c'.

Answer (score 0):

After all i used this small hack. Not pretty but does things.

```
if not os.path.exists( sys.argv[0] ):
        exe_path = psutil.Process(os.getppid()).cmdline()[0]
```